# Oracle APEX export PDF file name

Tags: oracle, pdf, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I am exporting a PDF report from Oracle APEX using a Report Query defined in Shared Components. By default, the file name for the generated PDF is the Report Query name. Is there a way to customize the name? I need to include a timestamp in it, however I cannot find any solution. I am not using any external tool for report generation, and the layout is defined in XSL-FO.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Create a PL/SQL process and use the following API:

```
APEX_UTIL.DOWNLOAD_PRINT_DOCUMENT (
        p_file_name           => 'myreport123',
        p_content_disposition => 'attachment',
        p_application_id      => :APP_ID,
        p_report_query_name   => 'report1',
        p_report_layout_name  => 'report1',
        p_report_layout_type  => 'rtf',
        p_document_format     => 'pdf');
```

The above code assumes that your Report Query Name and Report Layout Name are **report1**

Note that you can change p_file_name to whatever you like.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. i tried to do this: created a dynamic action dependent on a button click, and on its TRUE "branch" i put the code above, but nothing is happening. If I put the same code directly in the dynamic action as server side condition (I know, it is logically wrong, but i wanted to test the code) then it downloads a corrupted pdf file. Is the code above enough to launch the pdf download, or is it more of a function prtotype and I need to call it in another way?

Comment: OK, so the dynamic action seems to be incorrect. So now I am executing the pl/sql from a new page, activated by the button after submitting the page. it generates a non working pdf. Why?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using XSLT 2.0 or XSLT 3.0, you can get the current time (not the modification time of the source document) using `currentDateTime()`.  See https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-current-dateTime

If you are still using XSLT 1.0, your XSLT processor might implement the EXSLT extensions for date and time.  See http://exslt.org/date/index.html